# How to list contents of a directory IN ORDER with node.js?

Tags: javascript, list, node.js, directory, inorder

I'm a fairly experienced programmer and I've just recently discovered node.js. I love JavaScript because that's where I started (Web Development) so being able to write server-side code with its is amazing.

Currently, I'm working on a simple exercise, a WebSocket/HTTP server, and I began to add a directory list function when I ran into a slight annoyance: when I list directories and files in a certain directory they're not in any order. I would like them to be listed with directories first, files second than alphabetically (like the 'ls' command). I have a feeling its because its asynchronus but I'm not totally positive. Any help would be appreciated.

BTW, here's my code:

```
var sys = require("sys");
var ws = require('websocket-server');
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var url = require("url");

function log(data){
  sys.log("\033[0;32m"+data+"\033[0m");
}

var server = ws.createServer();
server.listen(3400);
log("Listening on 3400 for HTTP and WS");

server.addListener("request", function(request, response){
  log("HTTP: Connected: " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
  var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  var filename = path.join("/home/brandon", uri);
  log("HTTP: " + request.connection.remoteAddress + " Requested: " + filename);
  path.exists(filename, function(exists) {
        if(!exists) {
            response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write("404 Not Found\n");
            log("HTTP: " + filename + " Does Not Exist. 404 returned to " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
            response.end();
            log("HTTP: Disconnected: " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
            return;
        }

        fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function(err, file) {
            if(err) {
                if(err.errno === 21){
                    fs.readdir(filename, function(err1, files){
                        if(err1){ 
                            response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
                            response.write("Error when reading directory: " + err1 + "\n");
                            log("HTTP: " + filename + " Could Not Be Read. 500 returned to " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
                            response.end();
                            log("HTTP: Disconnected: " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
                            return;
                        } else {
                            response.writeHead(200);
                            response.write("<HTML><HEAD><title>Directory Listing for " + uri + "</title></HEAD><BODY><h1>Directory Listing for " + uri + "</h1>");
                            response.write("<ul>");
                            function printBr(element, index, array) {
                                response.write("<li>" + element + "</li>");
                            }
                            /*for( i in files ){
                                response.write("<li>" + files[i] + "</li>");
                            }*/
                            files.forEach(printBr);
                            response.write("</ul>");
                            response.write("</BODY></HTML>");
                            log("HTTP: Directory listing for " + filename + " sent to " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
                            response.end();
                            log("HTTP: Disconnected: " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    return;
                }
                response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
                response.write("Error when reading file: " + err + "\n");
                log("HTTP: " + filename + " Could Not Be Read. 500 returned to " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
                response.end();
                log("HTTP: Disconnected: " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
                return;
            }

            response.writeHead(200);
            response.write(file, "binary");
            log("HTTP: " + filename + " Read and Sent to " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
            response.end();
            log("HTTP: Disconnected: " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
        });
    });
});

server.addListener("connection", function(conn){
  log(conn.id + ": new connection");
  server.broadcast("New Connection: "+conn.id);
  conn.addListener("readyStateChange", function(readyState){
    log("stateChanged: "+readyState);
  });

  conn.addListener("close", function(){
    var c = this;
    log(c.id + ": Connection Closed");
    server.broadcast("Connection Closed: "+c.id);
  });

  conn.addListener("message", function(message){
    log(conn.id + ": "+JSON.stringify(message));

    server.broadcast(conn.id + ": "+message);
  });
});
```

And here's the output in the browser:
[image: Output in Browser]

## **SOLVED:**

Thanks to @Samir, I found out how to do exactly what I wanted to do. I iterated through the array of the directory contents, checked if an item was a directory or file, separated them into two arrays ('dirs_in' for dirs and 'files_in' for files), sorted the two arrays alphabetically, and finally wrote them out.

Code (Lines 42-70):

```
response.writeHead(200);
response.write("<HTML><HEAD><title>Directory Listing for " + uri + "</title></HEAD><BODY><h1>Directory Listing for " + uri + "</h1>");
response.write("<ul>");
function printBr(element, index, array) {
    response.write("<li>" + element);
    if( fs.statSync( path.join(filename + element) ).isDirectory() ){
        response.write(" is a <b>dir</b>");
    } else {
        response.write(" is a <b>file</b>");
    }
    response.write("</li>");
}
var dirs_in = [];
var files_in = [];
function sep(element, index, array) {
    if( fs.statSync( path.join(filename + element) ).isDirectory() ){
        dirs_in.push(element);
    } else {
        files_in.push(element);
    }
}
files.forEach(sep);
dirs_in.sort().forEach(printBr);
files_in.sort().forEach(printBr);
response.write("</ul>");
response.write("</BODY></HTML>");
log("HTTP: Directory listing for " + filename + " sent to " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
response.end();
log("HTTP: Disconnected: " + request.connection.remoteAddress);
```

Browser Output:
[image: Problem Solved]
P.S. I'll remove the 'is a dir' and 'is a file'. They were just for testing.

Comment: Even tho this question is answered, maybe you can define what it means to list the files in a directory "in order"?

Comment: `statSync` is not cheap and creates a horrible bottleneck in your code. Do not use `Sync` functions in a web server.

Comment: You can try the solution given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294186/express-js-any-way-to-display-a-file-dir-listing)7

Why rebuild the wheel? ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want them ordered by name, you can just call `sort()` on the array first.

```
files.sort().forEach(printBr);
```

If, for example, you'd like to sort directories first, then you need to get more information. A naive implementation would be to query the stats of each file in the sort comparison function:

```
files.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aIsDir = fs.statSync(dir + "/" + a).isDirectory(),
        bIsDir = fs.statSync(dir + "/" + b).isDirectory();
    
    if (aIsDir && !bIsDir) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (!aIsDir && bIsDir) {
        return 1;
    }

    return a.localeCompare(b);
}).forEach(printBr);
```

The [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method is what the `sort` method uses by default as the comparison function, so we delegate to that if they're both on "equal" terms. You can expand upon this as necessary. I'd also recommend you store the result of `isDirectory` in a map or something at the very least. In addition, [`statSync`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/fs.html#fs.statSync) is good for demonstration purposes, but not in production code. Use [`stat`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/fs.html#fs.stat) instead. This does lead to slightly more complex code, but the benefits of asynchronous behaviour are worth it.

Comment: This helps but I would like to list them by type first (e.g. directory or file) then by name. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a 'isDirectory' function somewhere in the API.

Comment: -1 for using `Sync` functions. They create horrible bottlenecks.

Comment: @Raynos: That's partially what I meant by "naive." How you use an async function will depend on your style and the code around it. At some point you're going to have to whack some sort of latch in, which is really beyond the scope of this question. I will add information on how to use `stat` to the answer.

Comment: naive is slow or sub-optimum. The above code creates a horrible bottleneck that stops the server from being able to scale. There's a difference between not efficient and critical bottleneck. It's just simply bad form to ever recommend using `Sync`.