# Express.js - any way to display a file/dir listing?

Tags: node.js, express

With [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) is there a way to display a file/dir listing like apache does when you access the URL of a directory which doesn't have a index file - so it displays a listing of all that directories contents?

Is there an extension or package that does this which I don't know of? Or will I have to code this myself?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As of Express 4.x, the directory middleware is no longer bundled with express. You'll want to download the npm module [serve-index](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index).

Then, for example, to display the file/dir listings in a directory at the root of the app called `videos` would look like:

```
    var serveIndex = require('serve-index');

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"))
    app.use('/videos', serveIndex(__dirname + '/videos'));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Extra question, if I'm serving a folder (as the root), then serving 2 directories (located elsewhere) as subfolders, they don't get listed when browsing the root. Anyway of fixing this?

Comment: Serve index doesn't allow to download the file , is there any way to download files from serve Index

Answer (score 46):

There's a brand new default [Connect middleware named `directory`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/directory.html) ([source](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/directory-folders/lib/middleware/directory.js)) for directory listings. It has a lot of style and has a client-side search box.

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function() {
  var hourMs = 1000*60*60;
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: hourMs }));
  app.use(express.directory(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I suggested an edit which was rejected for reasons beyond my understanding. > Since express got to 3.x `express.createServer()` is deprecated and should be replaced by `express()`. (see [change log](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) for more details)

Comment: The directory middleware has been split out and is now found here: https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index

Comment: I am getting errors not only on .createServer() as @JeremieParker describes but also on .configure();

Comment: that link is now a 404

Answer (score 15):

The following code will serve both directory and files

```
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
app.use('/p', serveIndex(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/p', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: This is an important thing to call out! It's not immediately obvious in the accepted answer that the files are accessible because the `serveIndex` root is below the static root. Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to make the listing chronological instead of alphanumerical with this?

Comment: `serveindex` serves both directory and files without this extra line as far as I'm aware..

Answer (score 14):

This will do the work for you: (new version of express requires separate middleware). E.g. you put your files under folder 'files' and you want the url to be '/public'

```
var express = require('express');
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
var app = express();

app.use('/public', serveIndex('files')); // shows you the file list
app.use('/public', express.static('files')); // serve the actual files
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks!
You can also do `serveIndex('files', {icons: true})` for icons.

Answer (score 3):

Built-in NodeJS module [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) gives a lot of fine-grained options

```
const fs = require('fs')

router.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const fullPath = process.cwd() + req.path //(not __dirname)
    const dir = fs.opendirSync(fullPath)
    let entity
    let listing = []
    while((entity = dir.readSync()) !== null) {
        if(entity.isFile()) {
            listing.push({ type: 'f', name: entity.name })
        } else if(entity.isDirectory()) {
            listing.push({ type: 'd', name: entity.name })
        }
    }
    dir.closeSync()
    res.send(listing)
})
```

Please make sure to read up on path-traversal security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Please only use hand crafted solutions like this on development environment, do not use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

How about this code?
Simple and can download files.
I found in [here](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index).

```
var express    = require('express')
var serveIndex = require('serve-index')

var app = express()

// Serve URLs like /ftp/thing as public/ftp/thing
// The express.static serves the file contents
// The serveIndex is this module serving the directory
app.use('/ftp', express.static('public/ftp'), serveIndex('public/ftp', {'icons': true}))

// Listen
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.