# How to I get the directory in Express with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create a server and I want to get the script, CSS and the library.

I can get the file, but I don't know how to get a directory:

```
app.get('/app.js', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/app.js', 'utf8', function(err, text){
        res.end(text);
    });
});
```

I want to get directory like above.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for function to read a directory `fs.readDir` should do the job for you. If you are looking for serving some static files it is better you use some framework such as "connect" (http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html), instead of writing all by yourself.

May you share what problem are you trying to solve? Someone can give you a much more precise answer in that case.

Please note I am also newbie to node.

Comment: it looks like he is using expressjs - which is built on top of connect.

Answer (score 4):

in express you can define/set a public dir:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

everything in there will be served like from a normal "fileserver".
if you want to have directory listings, take a look at this:
[Express.js - any way to display a file/dir listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294186/express-js-any-way-to-display-a-file-dir-listing)
or this
[How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a directory in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js)