# Making a specific directory browsable in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a directory with some images in it that I want to make viewable in a browser.

This directory lives on my server at /public/images

Inside /public I also have other directories that I do not want to make public, hence making the entire /public directory viewable is not the solution.

How can I using the connect directory middleware make just my /public/images browsable?

Using the [solution described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294186/express-js-any-way-to-display-a-file-dir-listing) makes everything in /public viewable and trying the following doesn't work :

```
    app.use(exp.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(exp.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
    app.use(exp.directory(__dirname + '/public/images'));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to mount your routes to a special path, like

```
app.use('/', exp.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/images', exp.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
app.use('/images',exp.directory(__dirname + '/public/images'));
```

This way you can access the content of /public with the url / and the content of /public/image with the url /images

Comment: I tried this while wanting to make a root-level directory available and it didn't work. I just added a folder called /ndn as a sibling to /public and I want to use a test.js script in a client view file from /views where a script src points to "/ndn/test.js" - how?

Comment: @Cody at least with express@3.0.0 this works like a charm - just allow access to the root level directory with express static middleware. Maybe there's a bug in your code?

Comment: Please note that express.directory is no longer bundled hence supported in Express ^4.X.X. You can use serve-index for it.

Answer (score 1):

Express 4:

```
npm install serve-index
```

--

```
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');

app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'), serveIndex(__dirname + '/public/images'));
```