# List static content on server and return it as JSON using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I have a very simple app serving static files:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/files'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

I'd like to make this app slightly smarter by responding to GET for **folders**. I mean, to **list the full list of files of the folder, in a JSON**.

For instance, for a GET at `localhost:8080/`, I would like the app to return:

```
[{
  "type" : "file",
  "name" : "file1.ext"
},
{
  "type" : "file",
  "name" : "file2.ext"
},
{
  "type" : "dir",
  "name" : "a-folder"
}]
```

instead of:

```
Cannot GET /
```

Is there a way to extend Express's static behaviour to achieve this?
If not, what approach would you recommend?

**EDIT**: I tried to use the `serve-index` middleware (formerly `directory`), which works well but unfortunately returns directly html, when I need raw JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

You need to use express.static:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use("/files",express.static('files'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Then you will be able to access the files as:

```
http://yourdomain.com/files/file.jpg
```

**EDIT** I just realized, you need the list of files in the dir.

- There you have an API to do that: https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index
- Also, there is a directory option in  Express:https://stackoverflow.com/a/6524266/3617531

There you have the answers, then, I´ll mark as duplicate

As commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25580289/3617531), maybe installing node utility glob (`npm install glob`), and code some express function for GET in `/files` dir this way:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var glob = require("glob")


//EDIT: As you commented, you should add this also here, to allow 
//  accessing the files inside the dir. It should not be a problem as 
//  GET only manages the requests to "/files" url, without a file name    
//  after it.

app.use("/files", express.static("/files"));

app.get('/files', function (req, res) {

//EDIT: USE WALK INSTEAD OF WALK TO GO UNDER CHILD DIRS
glob("*.ext", options, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
  // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
  // er is an error object or null.
  res.send(files);
});


});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

**WALK MODE: (FOR SUBDIRS, AS REQUIRED)**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var walk    = require('walk');
var ALLfiles   = [];

app.use("/files", express.static("/files"));

app.get('/files', function (req, res) {

//EDIT: If you need to go under subdirs: change glob to walk as said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js/25580289#25580289
  var walker  = walk.walk('./files', { followLinks: false });
   walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
       // Add this file to the list of files
       ALLfiles.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
       next();
   });

   walker.on('end', function() {
    res.send(ALLfiles);
   });

});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. I tried this, but this middleware returns HTML when I need JSON... Any suggestion ?

Comment: you will still need some coding, but i think it will be the easy way, maybe you´ll also need to JSON encode the array, but I think you will reach through it easily

Comment: Thanks for the update. One last question though: In this solution the files themselves are not served anymore. Is this code compatible with `app.use(express.static("files"))`? I would expect a logic somewhere like `if(isFile(file)) serveStaticFile(file) else serveFolderAsJSON(file)`.

Comment: I think you will not have any problem to combine them like this *** *check the answer edit i did right now plz

Comment: ***not pretty sure, but sure you can anyway, if it doesn´t work, to restrict the the `use` only to "/files/*" or similar

Comment: sorry, corrected to show better the comments. I think get will work anyway with this, as get checks the URL is exactly the same

Comment: is it working? maybe `app.use("files/*", app.static("/files"))`  is the solution?

Comment: Thanks again! We're getting closer, but still a problem: As is, it works for the directory `files/`, but not for any subdirectory. Can I use wildcards in the `get` route to get the same behaviour for any subfolder inside `file/`? (Also, from your answer you may remove `options`, and replace `*.ext` with `*`, as I need to list all files and all directories)

Comment: I thinks is more a GLOB thing:

Comment: yes, you will be able to use wildcards and regular expressions, or to use new get methods appart from this one, for each specific directory.

Comment: I undesrstood in my las post you were asking for al files in subdir, not for the subdirs to list their files