# app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname))) apparently doesnt work on my express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following express server:

```
path = require('path');
express = require('express');
app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

server = app.listen(80, function () {
    host = 'localhost';
    port = server.address().port;
    console.log('listening on http://'+host+':'+port+'/');
});
```

It supose to send me all files in the directory when i load `http://localhost` in the navigator, but it send me this text:

> Cannot GET /

Why it happens??? Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js - any way to display a file/dir listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294186/express-js-any-way-to-display-a-file-dir-listing)

Comment: well you are missing the '/' route.

Comment: There is a diference between express.js any way to display a file/dir listing, and an error happened with the answer of that question. At least I suppose. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: It doesnt work with `app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname)));`