# How to show all files in a folder as static files in express js?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to show all the files in the uploads folder as a list of files when serving via express.

Using `app.use(express.static("public"));` only serves individual files.

I cannot directly see all files in that folder like if I go to `localhost:3000/public`

Comment: what you're after is like FTP-Listing, and that can be accomplished [with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27391258/28004)

Comment: @balexandre Thanks a lot that worked. I couldn't google it the right way for some reason all the answers I got was just express.static solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution with the help of above comments thanks to @Balexandre.

```js
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")));
app.use("/public", serveIndex(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")));
```